# Performant way to check multiple columns in a dataframe against another column

Tags: python, pandas

Given a df of strings thus:

```
   id   v0    v1    v2     v3     v4
0   1  '10'   '5'  '10'   '22'   '50'   
1   2  '22'  '23'  '55'   '60'   '50'   
2   3   '8'   '2'  '40'   '80'  '110'  
3   4  '15'  '15'  '25'  '100'  '101'
```

I need to check if values in columns v0:4 are in a separate, second dataframe's ID column:

```
     ID   State 
0   '10'   'TX'
1   '40'   'VT'
2   '3'    'FL'
3   '15'   'CA'
```

If they are, I want to return which values existed as a new column:

```
    v0    v1    v2     v3     v4      matches
0  '10'   '5'  '10'   '22'   '50'   ['10','10']
1  '22'  '23'  '55'   '60'   '50'   ['']
2   '8'   '2'  '40'   '80'  '110'   ['40']
3  '15'  '15'  '25'  '100'  '101'   ['15','15']
```

I intend to use df.explode on that df, then left join it to the second dataframe.

At present, I'm doing this:

```
def match_finder(some_list):
    good_list = []
    for x in some_list:
        if second_df['ID'].str.contains(x).any():
            good_list.append(x)
            continue
        else:
            pass
    return good_list

df['matches'] = [
    match_finder([df.iloc[x]["v0"], df.iloc[x]["v1"], df.iloc[x]["v2"], df.iloc[x]["v3"], df.iloc[x]["v4"]])
    for x in range(len(df))]
```

This isn't throwing errors but it's extremely slow.

Comment: Add the sample for 2nd df as well.

Comment: Things are going to stay relatively slow if you require that list. There are many other ways to store the information without storing a complex object in each cell.

Comment: For instance, a very performant check would be to check `isin` and then `mask` the DataFrame values: `df1.set_index('id')[df1.set_index('id').isin(df2['ID'].to_numpy())]`. Same information but avoids the slow aggregation to a column of lists

Comment: I need to read up on to_numpy, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `where` and `isin` to select at once all the values in df v0:4 that are in second_df ID, then `stack` to remove the `nan`, `groupby` level=0 that is the original index of df and `agg` as `list`.  To add the missing values like your second row, you can use `reindex` with the original index of df.

```
df['matches'] = (df.filter(regex='v\d')
                   .where(lambda x: x.isin(second_df['ID'].to_numpy()))
                   .stack()
                   .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
                   .reindex(df.index, fill_value=[])
                )
print(df)
   id    v0    v1    v2     v3     v4       matches
0   1  '10'   '5'  '10'   '22'   '50'  ['10', '10']
1   2  '22'  '23'  '55'   '60'   '50'            []
2   3   '8'   '2'  '40'   '80'  '110'        ['40']
3   4  '15'  '15'  '25'  '100'  '101'  ['15', '15']
```

Comment: Extremely fast. On a df of >200k rows this completed in 18 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate over axis 1 using [`df.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) after identifying a potential match and filter NaN using [`pd.Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html)

```
v = df.loc[:,'v0':'v4']
m = v.isin(s['ID'].to_numpy()) # s is second datafrane
df['match'] = v[m].agg(lambda x: x[x.notna()].tolist(),axis=1)

   id    v0    v1    v2     v3     v4       matches
0   1  '10'   '5'  '10'   '22'   '50'  ['10', '10']
1   2  '22'  '23'  '55'   '60'   '50'            []
2   3   '8'   '2'  '40'   '80'  '110'        ['40']
3   4  '15'  '15'  '25'  '100'  '101'  ['15', '15']
```